# OpenLDAP ppolicy translations

Tags: centos, ldap, translation, openldap, gnome

I want to know if slapd or ppolicy support translation ?

Context :
I'm using LDAP Directory as a centralized authentication system. I have a server running slapd and clients using nss-pam-ldap to connect to the server.
ppolicy module is active, and I have configured a custom password policy.

Clients and server are running under Centos 7. Clients have a user interface (Gnome).

My problem :
When a user modify its password, he will receive some messages if its new password doesn't respect my password policy. For example :

- Password fails quality checking policy
- Please make sure the password meets the complexity constraints
- ...

Is their a way to translate these messages ? Users of clients are french and not fluent in english.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: The answer to this would be found at the openldap.org site.

Comment: If you find the answer on the website openldap.org, then you have won a beer . I have search all arround internet using multiple keywords before posting on stackowerflow.